# How can I limit size of a SQL Server table?

Tags: sql-server, limit, database-administration

For X and Y reasons, I cannot use any of the built-in audit capabilities of SQL Server (audit or CDC).

I'm forced to create a table to store everything related to traceability and event logs. Of course, this table has the potential to become HUGE and this presents a problem.

**Is there any way to limit the row size or MB size of a table, doing it so in such a way that when it reaches X amount of rows or MB's, the older rows are deleted to allow insertion of new ones?**

I guess I could trigger the bastard with an autonumeric field or some date column (in case my limit is defined by periods), but I'm asking, is there a more "classy" way to do it?

Comment: How about job that runs every night and delete oldest records if number of records exceed treshold?

Comment: @lad2025 unfortunately, since it's a system that's going to be in use 24/7, a nightly job might just not cut it (in case it was a particularly eventful day). But I guess going a few rows over the limit is fine, I'll have to check with the crazy project managers that tied my hands

Comment: you can definitely limit it to X number of rows following sokjukim's answer (ON INSERT triggers), assuming you only have data types of deterministic size, so no varchar(MAX) for instance, you can easily compute the maximal amount of rows you should keep.

Comment: @dhuesca It looks OK then to run the job every, say, hour.

Comment: I would advise against trying to keep only X amount based on size. If you want to maintain an audit, keeping X amount based on time is a better approach. And easier to implement (i.e. run a periodic job to trim the oldest bit).

Comment: maybe create other database to store table with this logs and make job to backup this database, delete and create new (in other order: rename database, create new, backup old and delete old). With this you dont have  any locks and performance impact to production database and you have all logs

Answer (score 1):

If there's strict rule to limit table size, trigger will be better. But it may have performance impact. Or you can use scheduled job to delete old records.

Comment: He mentioned that scheduled job might not make it, but something you can do is a loose "size limit" trigger. Instead of deleting the 501th row with every insert, you can simply delete all the rows that exceed 500 whenever you have more than 550 rows.